# weblogic server goes down when any database glitches occurs

Tags: weblogic

Dears,

I am facing a problem with my weblogic 12c Server. I have 3 managed nodes and one admin server. I have configured an Oracle Datasource. Whenever any network glitches or database downtime happens, weblogic server also goes down completely. Is there any configuration which I can make to hold on the server until everything comes back.

Servers are trying to restart automatically.But it is in STARTING state. I have to again start all servers and it is taking time. Your suggestions will help me a lot. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You probably check with weblogic team

Comment: Have you checked the log files for an explanation ?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want your servers to restart automatically, the server failure action can probably be tweaked:

{managed_server} -> Configuration -> Overload -> Failure Action

However, probably you should be more interested in exploring if you are missing connection timeout config for your datasource.